# How to get an addin to load in Visual Studio Experimental

Tags: visual-studio

I'm developing an addin for visual studio (2010) and want to debug it.  I found about the experimental instance of visual studio from here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oshryhorn/archive/2011/03/09/experimental-instance-of-vs-2010-safe-and-easy-debugging.aspx

However it doesn't go on to say how to register the addin for the experimental version only. I tried adding a folder key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp_Config\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders  but when starting the experimental instance my new key gets deleted and it never reads the .addin file  (which works if i put in the normal place and run the normal instance of VS so that bit is OK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

- Shut down all instances of Visual Studio
- Add your folder to the "VisualStudio\10.0Exp\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders" key (not 10.0Exp_Config).
- You will likely need to manually add both "AutomationOptions" and "LookInFolders"

After this new instances of Visual Studio looking at the experimental hive should see your folder.

Alternatively you can just add this through the options menu in the Visual Studio Experimental Instances.

- Tools -> Options
- Environment
- Add-in / Macros Security
- Add your folder via the "Add" button

Comment: Thanks - I used the UI option which created and added the key you mentioned